# Looking for a way to modify the splash screen list in tModLoader

Tags: c#, steam

Im new at modding Terraria with tModLoader, and im looking for a way to modify startup sequence and the splash pictures.
Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for any answers!

EDIT: I want to make a mod to modify the startup screen!
Sorry if I confused anyone before!

Comment: tModLoader is just a mod *loader*. See https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Mods

Comment: Thanks @Steve, but I already know that! Im looking for a way to modify the startup sequence by creating a mod. Sorry, I forgot to mention it in the post!